# Read dynamic log file name from configuration file in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I currently have all variables defined at the top of the Powershell script including log files that have dynamic names as such:

```
$log = '\\serv1\Log\dev-Log' + $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.log'
```

This will then give the $log variable a value of:

```
\\serv1\Log\dev-Log2017-10-20.log
```

I'm now planning on moving all of these environment specific variables to a separate XML configuration file and am not too sure how I can do similar with regard to the dynamic name.  I currently have an XML file that contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
    <process>FALSE</process>
    <xmlDir>\\serv1\dev</xmlDir>
    <scanDir>\\serv1\dev</scanDir>
    <processedDir>\\serv1\dev\done</processedDir>
    <errorDir>\\serv1\dev\err</errorDir>
    <log>\\serv1\dev\log\dev-Log' + $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.log</log>
</settings>
```

When I read in the config variables as below:

```
[xml]$configFile = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\settings.xml
$log = $configFile.settings.log
```

It gives me:

```
\\serv1\dev\log\dev-Log' + $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + '.log
```

Is there a way that I can make this log file name dynamic and is this the best way of retrieving the information from the XML?

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the date to be populated when the script is executed, you could put a placeholder in the XML and then replace it at time of execution. For example:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
    <process>FALSE</process>
    <xmlDir>\\serv1\dev</xmlDir>
    <scanDir>\\serv1\dev</scanDir>
    <processedDir>\\serv1\dev\done</processedDir>
    <errorDir>\\serv1\dev\err</errorDir>
    <log>\\serv1\dev\log\dev-Log##DATE##.log</log>
</settings>
```

Code:

```
[xml]$configFile = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\settings.xml
$log = $configFile.settings.log -Replace '##DATE##',(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other method: you can use -format (or -f) for this :

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>
    <process>FALSE</process>
    <xmlDir>\\serv1\dev</xmlDir>
    <scanDir>\\serv1\dev</scanDir>
    <processedDir>\\serv1\dev\done</processedDir>
    <errorDir>\\serv1\dev\err</errorDir>
    <log>\\serv1\dev\log\dev-Log{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.log</log>
</settings>
```

Code:

```
[xml]$configFile = get-content "c:\temp\test.xml.txt"
$configFile.settings.log -f (get-date)
```